# Establish a VPN behind an unknown router

Tags: vpn

I need to establish a VPN between my house and my mobile. But this is the scenario:

Mobile --> **Internet** --> Condo Router--> My house Cisco VPN Router (RV-110W)

The problem I have is that my house receives a UTP cable which I suspect comes from a central router for the whole condo. I do not have access to that router so I don't know what kind of router is, neither if I can do a port forward.

Any idea on how can I get that VPN working?

Comment: Do you have an externally visible IP address assigned your router?